# "Don't search" vs "don't be searching"

Tags: word-choice, tense

Can "don't search" and "don't be searching" used interchangeably for the present situation meaning "now"?

- Don't search for it. [in general/now.]
- Don't be searching for it. [now]

Answer (score 1):

Don't be searching for it is rather clunky, and in the imperative form you generally want to stick to shorter forms, such as the present itself, rather than conjugating it to perfect and progressive. Therefore "Don't search for it" is a better phrase.

Comment: The continuous in forms like *Don't be asking stupid questions!* sounds stereotypically ***Irish*** to me.

Answer (score 0):

For [now], you should use:

> Don't **go** searching for it.

since it is an action, not a state.

Comment: My teacher told me that this is also possible: You are kidding now. -> Dont be kidding now.

Comment: Don't kid me...